# Covid may cause brain to degenerate three times faster than normal?

Tags: covid-19, brain, research

I found this study on GB News: [Covid may cause brain to degenerate three times faster than normal, Oxford study suggests](https://www.gbnews.uk/news/covid-may-cause-brain-to-degenerate-three-times-faster-than-normal-oxford-study-suggests/242769)

After reading the article I still have a few questions. I found the study published in *Nature* referenced by the news article:
[SARS-CoV-2 is associated with changes in brain structure in UK Biobank](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-022-04569-5). Since I am not scientist, I would appreciate if someone could help me clarify some things around this study.

- How serious is the brain damage?
- How common is this type of brain damage?
- Are there any related studies that provide additional insight?

Comment: If you're interested in creating an account, I can merge this question into it so you can edit and interact with other users. Hopefully you'll still be able to comment here because of a cookie Stack Exchange saves that authenticates you.

Comment: The study you linked to was published only last week, and it made clear that much of what you're asking simply isn't known yet. So it's unlikely there is additional research published since then and that the unanswered questions have been answered. I would guess that a good answer to this question won't be possible for another year or more.